# How should we tag general .NET questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

It appears the tag wiki for [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) has changed to be exclusively about .NET Framework and points to use [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core). I know Microsoft did not do us any favors by renaming .NET Core 5 as just .NET 5.

How should we tag questions about .NET in general? I would have preferred keeping [.net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) and [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core)